# Returning the output of a function in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
f = [ 3,45,67,54,2,3]

def average(f)
    Numcount = 0
    Total = 0
    for n in f:
        Numcount =Numcount + 1
        Total = Total +n
    return (Total/Numcount)
```

I ran this code and it didn't display any error, neither did it display an output too

Comment: You never ran the function.

Comment: Invoke the function average

Answer (score 1):

You need a colon `:` when you define a function

`def average(f):`

You created a list `f` but you did not call the function you created. Try:

```
f = [3, 45, 67, 54, 2, 3]

def average(f):
    numcount = 0
    total = 0
    for n in f:
        numcount = numcount + 1
        total = total +n
    return (total/numcount)


print average(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The below section is called function definition.**

```
def average(f)
    Numcount = 0
    Total = 0
    for n in f:
        Numcount =Numcount + 1
        Total = Total +n
    return (Total/Numcount)
```

After Defining the function you have to call the function with some argument, if you defined the function in such a way.

```
result = average(f)
print(result)
```